# Library for text fetching from PDF document

Tags: android, pdf, text

I want to fetch a text from PDF document. Ideally with text attributes (fonts, colors, size etc).

I can’t found library which provide it.Maybe somebody knows such library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no one free library can provide it function. But [Mobi PDFViewer SDK](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/) can do it. Also it can reflow fetched text if you need.